# MaterialDesign Runtime Change Theme Wpf

Tags: wpf, material-design, themes

I want to change the theme of my project during the runtime. I want it to be Dark or Light mode. I am using MaterialDesign. There is a change of theme during runtime, but I cannot control the color. What is the point I missed?

My App.xaml Code

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionary1.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignExtensions;component/Themes/MaterialDesignLightTheme.xaml"/>


            <!-- primary colors -->
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/MaterialDesignColor.Blue.xaml" />
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueLightBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary100}"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueLightForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary100Foreground}"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrush" Color="#244886"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary500Foreground}"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueDarkBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary600}"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueDarkForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary600Foreground}"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>


            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignExtensions;component/Themes/MaterialDesignLightTheme.xaml"/>
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueLightBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary100}"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueLightForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary100Foreground}"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrush" Color="#244886"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary500Foreground}"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueDarkBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary600}"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueDarkForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary600Foreground}"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

My MaterialDesignDarkTheme.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestMaterialExtensions.Themes"
                xmlns:po="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options"
                >

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <!-- theme from MaterialDesignInXAML -->
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Dark.xaml"/>

    <!-- additional resources -->
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueLightBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary100}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueLightForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary100Foreground}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrush" Color="Red"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary500Foreground}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueDarkBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary600}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueDarkForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary600Foreground}"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

My MaterialDesignLightTheme.xaml

```
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <!-- theme from MaterialDesignInXAML -->
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />

    <!-- own themes -->

    <!-- additional resources -->
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueLightBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary100}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueLightForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary100Foreground}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrush" Color="Yellow"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary500Foreground}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueDarkBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary600}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueDarkForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary600Foreground}"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

My Change Theme Code

```
 public void SetLightDark(bool isDark)
    {
        var resources = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries;

        var existingResourceDictionary = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries
                                        .Where(rd => rd.Source != null)
                                        .SingleOrDefault(rd => Regex.Match(rd.Source.OriginalString, @"(\/MaterialDesignExtensions;component\/Themes\/MaterialDesign((Light)|(Dark))Theme)").Success);

        var source = $"pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignExtensions;component/Themes/MaterialDesign{(isDark ? "Dark" : "Light")}Theme.xaml";
        var newResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri(source) };

        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(existingResourceDictionary);
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(newResourceDictionary);
    }
```

Comment: I think there is an error in combining resource dictionaries. How can I combine source dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. The problem is that since I did not set the address paths of my xaml files in SetLightDark correctly, the address files I created could not be accessed at all.

Changing ThemeChange.cs Code

```
public void SetLightDark(bool isDark)
    {
        var resources = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries;

        var existingResourceDictionary = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries
                                        .Where(rd => rd.Source != null)
                                        .SingleOrDefault(rd => Regex.Match(rd.Source.OriginalString, @"(\/Themes\/MaterialDesign((Light)|(Dark))Theme)").Success);

        var source = $"pack://application:,,,/Themes/MaterialDesign{(isDark ? "Dark" : "Light")}Theme.xaml";
        var newResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri(source) };

        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(existingResourceDictionary);
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(newResourceDictionary);
    }
```

previous paths

```
$"pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignExtensions;component/Themes/MaterialDesign{(isDark ? "Dark" : "Light")}Theme.xaml"


\/MaterialDesignExtensions;component\/Themes\/MaterialDesign((Light)|(Dark))Theme)"
```

current path

```
@"(\/Themes\/MaterialDesign((Light)|(Dark))Theme)"

$"pack://application:,,,/Themes/MaterialDesign{(isDark ? "Dark" : "Light")}Theme.xaml"
```

**... My theme.xaml files are in a folder named Themes under the project.**